# Как запретить адаптивизацию письма в gmail?

Tags: вёрстка, email, gmail, вёрстка-email, email-layout

Во всех почтовых клиентах все прекрасно, кроме gmail. Этот клиент принудительно адаптирует ширину письма, от чего вся верстка едет. Да, можно нажать в меню кнопку - "Показать оригинал", но это не подходит, нужно показать нормальную верстку сразу. Фиксирую ширину каждого слоя, добавляю волшебный спейсер после боди:

```
<div style="display:none; white-space:nowrap; font:15px courier; line-height:0;"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </div>
```

увы, не помогает. Вот обертка моего письма:

```html
<table bgcolor="#F3F3F3"
       style="Margin:0;margin:0;padding: 0;font-family:'Arial',sans-serif;max-width:100%;padding:0;width:100%;background:#F3F3F3;">
  <style>
    a{
      text-decoration: none;
      color: inherit;
      color: inherit !important;
    }
    @media print{
      body, html{
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <center>
        <table width="600" bgcolor="#6999CC"
               style="Margin:0 auto;margin:0 auto;max-width:100%;width:600px;background:#6999cc;">
          <tbody bgcolor="#6999CC" style="background: #6999CC">
          <tr bgcolor="#6999CC" style="background: #6999CC">
            <td bgcolor="#6999CC" style="background: #6999CC">
              <center bgcolor="#6999CC" style="background: #6999CC">
                <table>
                  <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td height="4" style="height: 4px;line-height: 4px;">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <!--spacer-->

                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="570" ...
```

А когда писем становится несколько и они собираются в диалог, то их содержимое становится цитатами. И то, что стало цитатой, даже если показывалось раньше нормально, то теперь показывается не сверстанным. Так как gmail вырезает часть стилей этой прекрасной функцией.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта проблема была из-за того, что приложение само увеличивает ширфт по своему желанию. Чтобы запретить увеличение шрифта достаточно добавить строку с запретом переноса нужной ширины:

```html
<div style="white-space:nowrap!important;line-height: 0; color: #ffffff;">
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
</div>
```